# Redirect issues when upgrading CakePHP version with Cakedc/users

Tags: redirect, cakephp, cors, upgrade, cakedc

I am trying to upgrade the backend version from Cakephp3.8 to Cakephp4.4
I used upgrade tools and update composer and the versions of the modules.
One of the problem is that after upgrading, I have this kind of redirection problem.
For example, I tried to login and I call this endpoint - http://localhost:8765/api/users/login
in frontend, it says CORS error with 302, I think it's because the preflight has been redirected.
I also tested in postman and it says like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUbql.png)
It's the same with the other endpoint.

Here, I used CakeDC/Users module for authentication, and I also upgrade this from 8.5 to 9.0.1
I think the problem should be here but I couldn't find the solution after I tried to update the configuration.

Does anyone have this kind of problem before?
Please help me solve this issues.
Thanks.